# Is there a way in cypress to accomodate cy.get(`[data-cy="${test}"]`).filter(':visible') and cy.get(`[data-cy="${test}"]`) in a single code?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have a code like

```
cy.get(`[data-cy="${test}"]`).filter(':visible').click({force: true})
```

it works for some tests but for some elements there is no "filter" and those works without .filter(':visible'), so i am trying to accomodate both function in a single code to keep it generic for all kinds of buttons. Is there a way to do it?

I have tried few steps like:

```
cy.get(`[data-cy="${test}"]`).filter(':visible'|| ':hidden').click({force: true})
```

not sure whether it is right or wrong but its definielt not working!!

Comment: Why not just `cy.get(\`[data-cy="${test}"]\`).click()`

Comment: @Cully  some elements are weirdly used(In a dailog box) where we need to explicitly mention to click the elements by using .filter(':visible')

Comment: Are there elements with same data-cy attribute values on this page? If so, then you may want to make them more unique so you can eliminate this extra layer of logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `{force: true}` then it doesn't matter if the element is visible or hidden, cypress will click it. So in my opinion you don't need the filter option.

```js
cy.get(`[data-cy="${test}"]`).click({force: true})
```

Or, If you want to directly apply the OR condition in `.filter` you can do:

```js
cy.get(`[data-cy="${test}"]`).filter(':visible,:hidden').click({force: true})
```

Or, If you want to use If-Else you can do something like this:

```js
cy.get(`[data-cy="${test}"]`).then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.filter(':visible')) {
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
  } else if ($ele.filter(':hidden')) {
    cy.wrap($ele).click({force: true})
  }
})
```

Comment: some elements are weirdly used(In a dailog box) where we need to explicitly mention to click the elements by using .filter(':visible') but your by removing the filter its working but few other types of buttons its not clicking but it will click when i add .filter(':visible'). I guess i cannot make it generic function

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can look into method 2 or 3 then

Comment: Excellent perfect thank you 2nd method worked for me in both the conditions